# Fastest way to get tags containing text

Tags: python, lxml

I need to grab all the tags that contain text using `lxml.html`. I have been using `{e.tag for e in doc.xpath('.//*[text()= true()]')}`, but both wildcard and `text()` queries in `lxml` are notoriously slow. Is there a more speedy way to do it.

Comment: Could you provide some test data? The performance might depend on characteristics of the input data. How much faster do you need it to be?

Comment: Wildcards don't seem slow in 2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a set of tag names whose elements have some text:

```
tags = {e.tag for e in doc.iter() if e.text}
```

Comment: Thank you, this cuts it down from 1.3 ms to 400 us that is enough of a speed-up.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [e.tag for e in itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x.text,doc.findall('.//'))]
```

Not sure if it's faster, but it avoids both things you mentioned (XPath wildcards and `text()` function).

If you want to work with lists only (and not iterators), then this syntax is even simpler:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x.text,doc.findall('.//'))
```

You should use iterators if you process each tag as you find it (most likely faster).